# How to know that your Microsoft ClickOnce app will apply an update on next start?

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, clickonce

I have a C# WPF based app deployed via ClickOnce and I have the Updates setting to "After the application starts" set. This works as stated that when an update is available on first open after update released it will check after the app starts and then on the next open it will apply the update.

What I would like to know is how can I programmatically know that this will occur and that on the next launch an update will be applied? I want to show an indicator in the application to let the user know that there is an update waiting to be applied and that they need to restart. Similar to what chrome does in with the up arrow showing on the wrench icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gesh, 5 minutes after posting the question I eventually stumbled on this MSDN article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404263.aspx

It shows how to do this and other things within your app related to ClickOnce.